# Getting logical drives

Tags: c#, .net, drives

I use the following code to get logical drives:

```
string[] strDrives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
```

but when I want to iterate through it, an exception occurs, with the message:

```
Drive Not Ready
```

How can I get just ready drives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use DriveInfo to determine if the drive is ready.

```
foreach (var oneDrive in strDrives)
{
    var drive = new DriveInfo(oneDrive)
    if (drive.IsReady) 
    {
       // Do something with the drive...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also, of course, be achieved using Linq:

```
IEnumerable<DriveInfo> readyDrives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives()
    .Select(s => new DriveInfo(s))
    .Where(di => di.IsReady);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
string[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                           .Where(drive => drive.IsReady)
                           .Select(drive => drive.Name)
                           .ToArray();
```

`DriveInfo` provides a static `GetDrives` method, which returns an array of `DriveInfo` (`DriveInfo[]`) instances, representing information about each drive.

The `IsReady` property of each instance returns a boolean value indicating whether the drive can be read from or written to.

Drives which are not 'ready' throw exceptions when used, and rightly so: you cannot perform any operations on a drive which is not ready, so the best approach would be to throw an exception if someone did so, informing them of their mistake.

In the above code, I use LINQ's `Where` extension to iterate through the drives and discard the ones which are not ready.

Next, in the `Select` method of the same nature, I retrieve each drive's `Name` property, which represents the drive letter, such as `C:\` or `D:\`.

Finally, I call the `ToArray` method on the returned `IEnumerable`, which copies all of the elements in the enumerable into an array. I assume that you want the drive letters as an array.